# refute test failing even though answer is correct.

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am completing the Ruby exercises from exercism.io. I am currently working on the leap year problem.

Here is my code:

```
class Year
  DIVISORS = [4, 100, 400]

  def self.leap?(year)
    if is_year_leap?(year)
      "Yes, #{year} is a leap year"
    else
      "No, #{year} is not a leap year"
    end
  end

  def self.is_year_leap?(year)
    divisible_by = multiple_of(year)

    if !divisible_by[4]
      false
    elsif divisible_by[400]
      true
    end
  end

  def self.multiple_of(year)
    DIVISORS.each_with_object({}) do |divisor, multiple|
      multiple[divisor] = year % divisor == 0
    end
  end
end
```

(Note that the code is not complete yet, but it is giving me the right answer when I test the year 1997).

The test suite is as follows:

```
require 'date'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'leap'

class Date
  def leap?
    throw "Implement this yourself instead of using Ruby's implementation."
  end

  alias_method :gregorian_leap?, :leap?
  alias_method :julian_leap?, :leap?
end

class YearTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_leap_year
    assert Year.leap?(1996), 'Yes, 1996 is a leap year'
  end

  def test_non_leap_year
    refute Year.leap?(1997), 'No, 1997 is not a leap year'
  end

  def test_non_leap_even_year
    skip
    refute Year.leap?(1998), 'No, 1998 is not a leap year'
  end

  def test_century
    skip
    refute Year.leap?(1900), 'No, 1900 is not a leap year'
  end

  def test_fourth_century
    skip
    assert Year.leap?(2400), 'Yes, 2400 is a leap year'
  end
end
```

The failure I get when running my code is:

```
1) Failure:
YearTest#test_non_leap_year [leap_test.rb:20]:
No, 1997 is not a leap year

5 runs, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 3 skips

You have skipped tests. Run with --verbose for details.
```

Why is my test failing? I think it gets to the right answer, in that 1997 is not a leap year, but that doesn't satisfy the test.

Answer (score 1):

Your `leap?` method is supposed to return simply `true` or `false`, not the strings that you are returning.

The messages ('Yes, 1996 is a leap year', etc) are attached to the tests and display when the test fails.  The test is not asking for you to actually return those messages.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you don't mind marking this answer as correct, that would be great!  :)

Answer (score 0):

The `leap?` method returns a string, not a boolean so you should test its output with `assert_equal` with:

```
assert_equal 'No, 1997 is not a leap year', Year.leap?(1997)
```